# Python is in path, but still not opening in Windows 10 [python]

Tags: python, windows

I've seen all the posts on the topic, so please don't point me to another post. I've tried them all.

I editted the system variables "path" to include the directory to where python was installed.

[Terminal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02rI0.png)

As you can see, it's in the path.  Yet when I type `python` in the command prompt, it does not recognize it. I've refreshed the command prompt and even restarted the computer. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p26sH.png) with possible missing \

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWXCx.png) with \ not added to fresh command prompt.

Comment: does `python.exe` work?

Comment: yes, it gives me a python shell.

Comment: Is python working in CMD when you enter `python`?

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a \ missing in the end of the path of python directory. Could you please fix it and try to run it again?

Comment: I added the \ but it doesn't add it when I type path in a fresh command prompt. It shows up in the environmental variables though.

Comment: you have 2 entries for python on the path. one in middle (that got added the \) and one in the end. could you try running python again? and then python.exe?

Comment: Weird. The one on the end nor vscode path doesn't appear in the environment variables. How would I add a \ to that one if it doesn't appear?

Comment: it is probably created by a script on your installation that got the wrong path

Answer (score -1):

For anybody else currently having this issue, I fixed it for myself somehow. I was unable to get it running for some reason when I downloaded directly from Python. Unfortunately, I do not have a MAC and cannot help relaying info for that area, but I will say I had the exact same issue and it is resolved. For myself, I don't think I had some outside factor from a script source messing with my install...but maybe since I had a couple downloaded. Yet, what fixed this was un-installing the original install from Python and then re-installing it through the Windows app store instead. After that, I was able to not only run it, but have it recognized in my command promp (which wasn't happening prior). It works smoothly now, so if anybody using PC has a similar issue this year, try doing that.